# Does anyone have references on how to port aspectj based maven module to bazel

Tags: maven, bazel, aspectj-maven-plugin

Currently I am porting a maven based project to `bazel` and looking for documentation on how to port `aspectj-maven-plugin` related configurations to `bazel`

Ported java modules to `bazel`, tried adding `jvmflags` to tests

```
java_library(
    name="module-core",
    deps=[
        "@org_aspectj_aspectjrt//jar",
        "@org_aspectj_aspectjtools//jar",
        "@org_aspectj_aspectjweaver//jar",
        "@org_jetbrains_annotations//jar",
        "@org_springframework_spring_aop//jar",
        "@org_springframework_spring_aspects//jar",

    ]
)
```

Weaving of the classes is not happening

Answer (score 1):

```
def _aspectj_library_impl(ctx):
class_jar = ctx.outputs.class_jar

compile_time_jars_transitive = []
runtime_jars_transitive = []
exported_java_infos = []
for dep in ctx.attr.deps:
    compile_time_jars_transitive += [dep[JavaInfo].transitive_compile_time_jars]
    runtime_jars_transitive += [dep[JavaInfo].transitive_runtime_jars]
    exported_java_infos.append(dep[JavaInfo])
compile_time_jars = depset(
    transitive = compile_time_jars_transitive,
)
runtime_jars = depset(
    transitive = runtime_jars_transitive,
)
compile_time_jars_list = compile_time_jars.to_list()

aspect_libs_jars_transitive = []
for lib in ctx.attr.aspect_libs:
    aspect_libs_jars_transitive += [lib[JavaInfo].compile_jars]
aspect_libs_jars = depset(
    transitive = aspect_libs_jars_transitive,
)
aspect_libs_jars_transitive = ["a"]

# Cleaning build output directory
build_output = class_jar.path + ".build_output"
cmd = "set -e;rm -rf " + build_output + "\n"

java_runtime = ctx.attr._jdk[java_common.JavaRuntimeInfo]
java_path = "%s/bin/java" % java_runtime.java_home
java_tools = "%s/lib/tools.jar" % java_runtime.java_home

aspectj_tools_path = ctx.attr.aspectj_tools[JavaInfo].outputs.jars[0].class_jar.path
cp = ctx.configuration.host_path_separator.join([
    java_tools,
    aspectj_tools_path,
])

# Building ajc parameters
ajc_main_class = "org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main"
ajc_params = [java_path, "-cp", cp, ctx.attr._xmx, ajc_main_class]

if ctx.attr.ajc_opts:
    ajc_params.append(ctx.attr.ajc_opts)
if compile_time_jars:
    ajc_params.append("-classpath")
    ajc_params.append(cmd_helper.join_paths(ctx.configuration.host_path_separator, compile_time_jars))

ajc_params.append("-aspectpath")
ajc_params.append(cmd_helper.join_paths(ctx.configuration.host_path_separator, aspect_libs_jars))
ajc_params.append("-inpath")
for javaoutput in ctx.attr.input_jar[JavaInfo].outputs.jars:
    ajc_params.append(javaoutput.class_jar.path)
ajc_params.append("-outjar")
ajc_params.append(class_jar.path)

ajc = " ".join(ajc_params)
cmd += ajc

ctx.actions.run_shell(
    inputs = (compile_time_jars_list + ctx.files._jdk + ctx.files.input_jar),
    outputs = [class_jar],
    mnemonic = "JavacBootstrap",
    command = cmd,
    use_default_shell_env = True,
)

runfiles = ctx.runfiles(collect_data = True)
compile_time_jars = depset(transitive = [compile_time_jars], direct = [class_jar])
runtime_jars = depset(transitive = [runtime_jars], direct = [class_jar])

return [
    DefaultInfo(
        files = depset([class_jar]),
        runfiles = runfiles,
    ),
    JavaInfo(
        output_jar = class_jar,
        compile_jar = class_jar,
        exports = exported_java_infos,
    ),
]

aspectj_library = rule(
_aspectj_library_impl,
attrs = {
    "_jdk": attr.label(
        default = Label("@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:current_java_runtime"),
        providers = [java_common.JavaRuntimeInfo],
    ),
    "_xmx": attr.string(
        default = "-Xmx64M",
    ),
    "input_jar": attr.label(
        mandatory = True,
        allow_files = [".jar"],
    ),
    "aspectj_tools": attr.label(
        mandatory = True,
        allow_files = [".jar"],
    ),
    "ajc_opts": attr.string(
        mandatory = False,
        doc = "command options for ajc tool",
    ),
    "aspect_libs": attr.label_list(
        mandatory = True,
        allow_files = [".jar"],
    ),
    "deps": attr.label_list(
        allow_files = False,
        providers = [JavaInfo],
    ),
},
outputs = {
    "class_jar": "lib%{name}.jar",
},
fragments = ["java"],
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though the link might answer the question, it would be better to add the consolidated details out here.

Answer (score 0):

Bazel does not auto-magically apply java plugins and annotation processors.  These must be set up in the rules appropriately.  Just including the jars as a dependency does nothing.  Unfortunately (at the time of this writing) there is no aspect_java_plugin rule or anything like that, that you could use to pull it in. You could possibly use a genrule() to invoke the command-line that would do your bytecode weaving, but it won't happen automatically.