# How to use aspect oriented programming in a multi project java/scala repo built using Bazel

Tags: java, scala, gradle, aop, bazel

So I am fairly new to Bazel and I am migrating my code from gradle. My code is a Java project which has multiple modules in it. I am using AOP to intercept calls made to a particular function (not my own function, but some other dependency's function). Suppose I have 3 projects within my repo:

```
project(':project-a')
project(':project-b')
project(':project-c')
```

The function is being called at multiple places in A, B. A is written in Java and B is in scala. I am using gradle to build the entire repo. I am using the plugin and dependency:

```
plugin: 'io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving'    // This supports both compileJava and compileScala
"org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.6.aspectj"
```

The aspect is written in Java and is present in the C project, it will have the code which should run everytime the function is called in A or B. I apply the configurations to both these A and B subprojects:

```
subproject.tasks.compileJava {    // compileScala in case of project B
    ajc.options.compilerArgs = ["-sourceroots", "${rootDir}/project-c/src/main/java" ]
}
```

This works for my gradle project, but I wanted to know if I have anything similar in Bazel that could make it simple for me to achieve the same. The project structure remains the same. I want it so that it doesn't take too much time to intercept these calls as well, it should not affect the performance of my project. Can someone give me a simple multi-project code similar to mine where AOP is being used.

I did go through https://bazel.build/extending/aspects but I wasn't able to figure out how to do this, not sure if it even is the right resource to be looking at for my case.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: As for the Bazel link you shared, if you even start to read it, you will notice that it describes how to extend the Bazel build system as such using AOP-style code. It is not about adding AspectJ compilation to your target modules. What you are looking for is an AspectJ Bazel extension. Not being a Bazel user myself, I simply used Google for a few seconds and found https://github.com/ArvinZheng/Bazel-aspectj_rule and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58071267/1082681. Out of the box, there does not seem to be any comprehensive de-facto standard add-on.